# How to follow lazy loading with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, lazy-loading

I am trying to crawl a page that is using lazy loading to get the next set of items. My crawler follows normal links, but this one seems to be different:

The page:
https://www.omegawatches.com/de/vintage-watches

is followed by https://www.omegawatches.com/de/vintage-watches?p=2

But only if you load it within the browser. Scrapy will not follow the link.

Is there a way to make scray follow the pages 1,2,3,4 automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The page follows Virtual scrolling and the api through which it gets data is

`https://www.omegawatches.com/de/vintage-watches?p=1&ajax=1`

it returns a json data which contains different details including products in html format, and if the next page exist or not in a `a` tag with class `link next`

increase the page number till there is no `a` tag with `link next` class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The number is simply apended with 1,2,3.. but I honestly don't know how to do that, I have for now simply put 100 urls into the list, which works but it would be great to have that automated and to know when it stops.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is using start_urls so, if you really want to provide an example, you could provide a simple snippet that yields from start_requests() with range().